# ESP32 - Social distance detector - code

Tags: esp32

I recently got an ESP32-CAM for a project of mine. I was planning to attach an ultrasonic sensor to it, and when the ESP32 CAM detects a face, it would send a signal to the ultrasonic sensor to start measuring, and then the LCD would display the distance.

The original plan was to let the CAM code run on the ESP32-CAM module, and the ultrasonic sensor code on the Arduino Uno, but I cannot find a way to do let both programs communicate with each other, or putting them in one program. Any ideas?

The ESP32 Cam is connected to the Arduino Uno using rx and tx.

I am trying to combine these two programs:

This is the ESP32-CAM code:

```cpp
#include <ArduinoWebsockets.h>
#include "esp_http_server.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "camera_index.h"
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include "fb_gfx.h"
#include "fd_forward.h"
 
 
const char* ssid = "Manitoba";
const char* password = "pjq20070616";
 
// Arduino like analogWrite
// value has to be between 0 and valueMax
void ledcAnalogWrite(uint8_t channel, uint32_t value, uint32_t valueMax = 180)
{
  // calculate duty, 8191 from 2 ^ 13 - 1
  uint32_t duty = (8191 / valueMax) * min(value, valueMax);
  ledcWrite(channel, duty);
}
int pan_center = 90; // center the pan servo
int tilt_center = 90; // center the tilt servo
 
#define CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER
#include "camera_pins.h"
 
using namespace websockets;
WebsocketsServer socket_server;
 
static inline mtmn_config_t app_mtmn_config()
{
  mtmn_config_t mtmn_config = {0};
  mtmn_config.type = FAST;
  mtmn_config.min_face = 80;
  mtmn_config.pyramid = 0.707;
  mtmn_config.pyramid_times = 4;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.score = 0.6;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.candidate_number = 20;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.score = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.candidate_number = 10;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.score = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.candidate_number = 1;
  return mtmn_config;
}
mtmn_config_t mtmn_config = app_mtmn_config();
 
httpd_handle_t camera_httpd = NULL;
 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
 
  // Ai-Thinker: pins 2 and 12
  ledcSetup(2, 50, 16); //channel, freq, resolution
  ledcAttachPin(2, 2); // pin, channel
 
  ledcSetup(4, 50, 16);
  ledcAttachPin(12, 4);
 
  ledcAnalogWrite(2, 90); // channel, 0-180
  delay(1000);
  ledcAnalogWrite(4, 90);
 
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  //init with high specs to pre-allocate larger buffers
  if (psramFound()) {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }
#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
  pinMode(13, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(14, INPUT_PULLUP);
#endif
  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
 
  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_QVGA);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
 
  app_httpserver_init();
  socket_server.listen(82);
 
  Serial.print("Camera Ready! Use 'http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("' to connect");
}
 
static esp_err_t index_handler(httpd_req_t *req)
{
  httpd_resp_set_type(req, "text/html");
  httpd_resp_set_hdr(req, "Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  return httpd_resp_send(req, (const char *)index_ov2640_html_gz, index_ov2640_html_gz_len);
}
 
httpd_uri_t index_uri = {
  .uri       = "/",
  .method    = HTTP_GET,
  .handler   = index_handler,
  .user_ctx  = NULL
};
 
void app_httpserver_init ()
{
  httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
  if (httpd_start(&camera_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK)
    Serial.println("httpd_start");
  {
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &index_uri);
  }
}
 
static void draw_face_boxes(dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix, box_array_t *boxes)
{
  int x, y, w, h, i, half_width, half_height;
  fb_data_t fb;
  fb.width = image_matrix->w;
  fb.height = image_matrix->h;
  fb.data = image_matrix->item;
  fb.bytes_per_pixel = 3;
  fb.format = FB_BGR888;
  for (i = 0; i < boxes->len; i++) {
 
    // Convoluted way of finding face centre...
    x = ((int)boxes->box[i].box_p[0]);
    w = (int)boxes->box[i].box_p[2] - x + 1;
    half_width = w / 2;
    int face_center_pan = x + half_width; // image frame face centre x co-ordinate
 
    y = (int)boxes->box[i].box_p[1];
    h = (int)boxes->box[i].box_p[3] - y + 1;
    half_height = h / 2;
    int face_center_tilt = y + half_height;  // image frame face centre y co-ordinate
 
    //    assume QVGA 320x240
    //    int sensor_width = 320;
    //    int sensor_height = 240;
    //    int lens_fov = 45
    //    float diagonal = sqrt(sq(sensor_width) + sq(sensor_height)); // pixels along the diagonal
    //    float pixels_per_degree = diagonal / lens_fov;
    //    400/45 = 8.89
 
    float move_to_x = pan_center + ((-160 + face_center_pan) / 8.89) ;
    float move_to_y = tilt_center + ((-120 + face_center_tilt) / 8.89) ;
 
    pan_center = (pan_center + move_to_x) / 2;
    Serial.println(pan_center);
     int reversed_pan_center = map(pan_center, 0, 180, 180, 0);
    ledcAnalogWrite(2, reversed_pan_center); // channel, 0-180
 
    tilt_center = (tilt_center + move_to_y) / 2;
    ledcAnalogWrite(4, tilt_center); // channel, 0-180
 
  }
}
 
void loop()
{
  auto client = socket_server.accept();
  camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
  dl_matrix3du_t *image_matrix = NULL;
 
  while (true) {
    client.poll();
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
    image_matrix = dl_matrix3du_alloc(1, fb->width, fb->height, 3);
 
    fmt2rgb888(fb->buf, fb->len, fb->format, image_matrix->item);
 
    box_array_t *net_boxes = NULL;
    net_boxes = face_detect(image_matrix, &mtmn_config);
 
    if (net_boxes) {
      draw_face_boxes(image_matrix, net_boxes);
      free(net_boxes->score);
      free(net_boxes->box);
      free(net_boxes->landmark);
      free(net_boxes);
    }
 
    client.sendBinary((const char *)fb->buf, fb->len);
 
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    fb = NULL;
    dl_matrix3du_free(image_matrix);
  }
}
```

And here is the ultrasonic code:

```cpp
#include <HCSR04.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define trigPin 7
#define echoPin 6
#define buzzer 9
#define backlight 10

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 8);
UltraSonicDistanceSensor distanceSensor(trigPin, echoPin);

int tempReading;
double tempK;
float tempC;
int rounded;
int temp_round;
volatile boolean modes = 0;
double distance;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  attachInterrupt(0, changeMode, FALLING);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(backlight, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(backlight, HIGH);
  backlightOn();
}

void loop() {
  tempReading = analogRead(A0);
  tempK = log(10000.0 * ((1024.0 / tempReading - 1)));
  tempK = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * tempK * tempK )) * tempK );
  tempC = tempK - 273.15;
  distance = distanceSensor.measureDistanceCm(tempC);
  temp_round = round(tempC);
  if (modes == 1) {
    backlightOn();
    if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
      rounded = 0;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Out of range");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
    }
    else {
      rounded = round(distance);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Distance: ");
      lcd.print(rounded);
      lcd.print(" cm");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Temperature:" + String(temp_round) + " C");
    }
  } else {
    if (distance >= 300 || distance <= 0) {
      lcd.print("Out of range");
    }
    else {
      rounded = round(distance);
      if (distance >= 200) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Out of range");
      }
      else if (distance <= 200 && distance > 100) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Please keep away");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Distance:");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
      }
      else if (distance <= 100 && distance > 50) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("Keep away");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Distance:");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
        delay(200);
        tone(9, 260, 200);
        backlightOff();
        delay(100);
        backlightOn();
        delay(100);
      }
      else if (distance <= 50) {
        backlightOn();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("STAY AWAY!");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("Distance:");
        lcd.print(rounded);
        lcd.print(" cm");
        delay(100);
        tone(9, 260, 200);
        backlightOff();
        delay(100);
        backlightOn();
        delay(100);
        tone(9, 260, 200);
        backlightOff();
        delay(100);
        backlightOn();
      }
    }
  }
  delay(700);
}

void changeMode() {
  modes = !modes;
}

void backlightOn() {
  digitalWrite(backlight, HIGH);
}

void backlightOff() {
  digitalWrite(backlight, LOW);
}

void buzz() {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
}

void unbuzz() {
  digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Is `measureDistanceCm()` a blocking function call? If so, I have written about how to do non-blocking cooperative multitasking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032992/4561887.

Comment: you could use normal serial communication for communicating between the Arduino and esp32.

Comment: @xboxgamer is correct. That might be the quickest solution. Nevertheless, the one controller is definitely capable of doing both things at once. You just have to do the proper multi-tasking and do the work to make it happen.

Comment: yes the esp32 can do both at the same time. BTW if you don't know the esp32 has 2 cores so multitasking would be even more easier to achieve with the esp32.

Comment: @xboxgamer I believe that serial communication would require two separate boards(?) The ESP32-CAM I am having right now can only be connected to the arduino. Will just alternating the boards (Tools - board) work?

Comment: You have to switch com ports on the Arduino ide to recive data from different devices.